# How to explain implementation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am really new in Kotlin programming language. I work with generic types and I found code statements shown below. What does it means? What is the meaning of each line?

```kotlin
class s(val b: t) : t by b {
    fun f1(): Int = b.f3 + 1
    override fun f2(g: Int): Any? = when {
        g == 0 -> null
        else -> b.f2(g - 1)
    }
    override fun l(g: Int, h: k?, z: m):
            k = when {
        g == 0 -> z.f1.f2.f3(1, z, true)
        else -> b.l(g - 1, h, z)}}
    override fun f4 (g: Int): Short = when {
        g == 0 -> 0
        else -> b.f4(g - 1)}}}
```

Comment: where are the generics in that case?

Comment: It would help if you could [post the code as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), not as an image.  But at first glance it looks like that code is pretty incomprehensible; meaningless class/function/variable names, no comments, not enough whitespace…  It's also hard to interpret out of context — in particular, `t` must be defined somewhere, and that seems to be the only generic type.

Comment: Where did this code come from? It looks like it's been obfuscated. I don't blame you for having trouble reading code where the names have all been mangled.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to provide a meaningful answer here. This code is unreadable and there's no way to explain what it does, especially when the context is not provided. Please ask a more specific question.